# PUT request not working in Node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update an existing document in mongodb with node.js. But it does not seem to work. It do not even display the request call in the console. Please suggest what mistake I am doing or how I can I do the update operation in node.js with mongodb. Here is the code:

Node.js Code:

```
app.put('/addIssueId', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Adding issue id")
    console.log(req.body.issueKey)
    impactMapFeature.update( {productName:req.params.productName, actor:req.body.actor, activity:req.body.activity,feature:req.body.feature},{issueKey:req.body.issueKey}, function ( err, data ) {
        console.log("Updating" + data)
    });
});
```

Angular Controller code:

```
var data = {
    productName: $scope.productName,
    actor: actor,
    activity: impact,
    feature : $('#feature').val(),
    issueKey : data.key
};
     $http.put('/addIssueId', data)
            .success(function(data){

         }).error(function(data){
                            console.log('Error in adding issueId' + data)
         });
       }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `{productName: req.params.productName, ...}` be `{productName: req.body.productName, ...}`?

Comment: It seems to be working but why I donot get similar to  PUT /addIssueId 200 17ms  in console as I get for POST/GET/DELETE

Comment: It's because `req.params` is for the route parameters, not your data hence you are missing the `productName` route parameter `app.put('/addIssueId/:productName', ..` and on the client as `$http.put('/addIssueId/' + $scope.productName, ...`

Answer (score 1):

As chridam said, you are using req.params which is a route parameter. Either use the following route : `/addIssueId/:productName` or pass your variable with a query parameter : `/addIssueId?productName=productName` and `{productName = req.query.productName, ... }`, or pass your variable as you are doing it in the body (then you just need to change `req.params.productName` to `req.body.productName`